# RecyclerView that's supposed to diplay cardViews doesn't show anything

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerView that must show a list of cards, but it doesn't!
There is an arrayList of recipes get passed to the adapter to display them as cardviews, everything in the debugging seems to be alright, but it doesnt display anything on the screen.
 ViewHolder:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.nd.ameer.bake.R;

public class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titleTextView;
    public ImageView coverImageView;

    public RecipeViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        coverImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipeImageView);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.nd.ameer.bake.R;
import com.example.nd.ameer.bake.models.Recipe;
import com.example.nd.ameer.bake.views.holders.RecipeViewHolder;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecipeAdapter extends 

RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeViewHolder> {


    ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public RecipeAdapter(ArrayList<Recipe> recipes, Context context) {
        this.recipes = recipes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item, parent, false);
        return new RecipeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.coverImageView.setImageResource(R.color.colorPrimaryLight);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(recipes.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recipes.size();
    }
}
```

Fragment onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe, container, false);

    createRecipes();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recipe);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    if (recipes.size() > 0 & recyclerView != null) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecipeAdapter(recipes, getContext()));
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

The method  createRecipes(); creates a list of recipes and then it get passed to the adapter.

[as you can see, the recipes size is 4, so it's not the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqhec.png)

Comment: Are you sure the size of the list `recipes` is not 0?

Comment: Yeah it's always 4, the same list

Comment: can you post your createRecipes() code and logcat logs

Comment: it only parses a json string with another class, but it works well, the problem is with another thing

Comment: link to the json
https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json

Comment: Code you posted is ok, so there must be problem somewhere else. Check layouts (layou_widht and layou_height of recylerview and recipe_item).

Comment: I also did but id didn't help :)

Comment: Hi @A.Taweel can you post the entire content of your fragment file?
I'm sure there is something wrong with your `createRecipes()` method

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know the cause of the problem till now, but I moved both the adapter and the view holder to the Recipes Fragment as inner classes, and this has fixed the problem.